# Error when clearing multiple cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Worksheet_Change to make a value (either 1 or 0) appear in the next cell (Bx) when a value is entered in a range of cells (A1:A10).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = 1 Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1 
        Else:
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0 
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

The problem occurs when I try to clear the cells in column A.
When I select the cells I want to clear and press "Delete" I get "Run-time error '13' - Type mismatch" on the line "IF Target.Value = 1".

I would also like the cells in the B column to be cleared if I clear cells in the A column. E.g. if I delete cell A2:A5, B2:B5 should be cleared.

From what I understand the problem is that when selecting multiple cells it returns an array as the Target, and this is a mismatch with the Integer.

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: Add `if target.count>1 then exit sub` at the beginning. Or you could loop through `target` to allow multiple changes.

Comment: @SJR Thanks! How do I loop through `target` ? I would like the cells in the B column to be cleared if I clear cells in the A column. E.g. if I delete cell A2:A5, B2:B5 should be cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You need to cater for multiple cells in some way, for the reasons you mention, and add an extra clause to your `If`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r As Range, r1 As Range

Set r = Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10"))

If Not r Is Nothing Then
    For Each r1 In r
        If r1.Value = 1 Then
            r1.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1
        ElseIf r1.Value = vbNullString Then
            r1.Offset(0, 1).Value = vbNullString
        Else
            r1.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0
        End If
    Next r1
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In a first step we add the functionality that multiple cells are selected and changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change_Var1(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim targetCell As Range
    'If Target.Range.count
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
            For Each targetCell In Target
            If targetCell.Value = 1 Then
                targetCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1
            Else
                targetCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0
            End If
            Next targetCell
        Else
            If Target.Value = 1 Then
                Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1
            Else
                Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In the 2nd step we understand that also the "one cell" case can be handled in the same way and we add an if clause for the "cell(s) cleared" case:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim targetCell As Range
    'If Target.Range.count
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each targetCell In Target
            If targetCell.Value = 1 Then
                targetCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1
            Else
                targetCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0
            End If

            'if cell in col A is empty, then clear cell in col B
            If targetCell.Value = "" Then targetCell.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
        Next targetCell
    End If
End Sub
```